# Changes to XPages application not shown

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Server: Domino 8.5.3 / Window 2003 5.2

We have a strange Problem. Since a few days, we cannot apply changes to our XPage application. Even, if we make some few text changes and open the application, the changes are not displayed. We looked into the generated XPage-Java-classes, here we can see, that the changes were applied to these classes.

Also, we tried to create a new Test-XPage, but if we open this xpage, the error "404 item not found" is displayed.

We also tried this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21327454 but it doesn't help....

We have already restarted the http task and the server.

Comment: try to make new copy.

Answer (score 5):

It looks very much like your XPages don't compile anymore. You can check that by opening the Navigator view in the Domino Designer and check webContent/web-inf/classes. Every XPage translates into a Java class and it seems that has stopped. You can try the Project menu option "clean" and you want to right click on the nsf and check the project properties if a builder has been disabled or is missing. 
Next stop: reinstall Designer. Since the compilation happens in Designer, that's where you need to look

Comment: dosn't help.... we now have created a new empty database, copied all design elements "by hand"... now it works. Thanks!

Comment: One trick to try: link to an On disk project, export, unlink, link an empty nsf,  import.

Comment: If you don't mind to share the broken NSF,  we could a dev have  a look if there is something that needs attention in the product